# how should I rotate an image continuously using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an image which I want to rotate continuously.

I thought of rotating it through a certain angle after specific interval of time . However, I wanted to implement a feature of shooting a bullet in the direction my head of the image is pointing at that moment of time when I click a specific key.

So at that moment of time , how should I keep the track of my head in the rotating image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating rotated images is computationally expensive.  It is something that should be done *once* before your program enters its main loop.

A "continuously rotating" image is really a set of animation frames, each one advanced by some degree from the previous.

The pygame function `pygame.transform.rotate()` will rotate an image.  It might be useful in your case to decide some step-angle, then make *N* images.

For example, if you desired 12 frames of rotation animation, create 11 more frames of animation each rotated by 360 / 12 degrees (is this off-by-one?).

This gives us a simple sprite class, which pre-creates the frames at the time of instantiation.  Obviously if you had lots of sprites, it does not make sense to re-compute the same frames for each of them, but it serves as an example.

```
class RotatingSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

    def __init__( self, bitmap, rot_count=12 ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.rect        = bitmap.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
        # start with zero rotation
        self.rotation    = 0
        self.rotations   = [ bitmap ]
        self.angle_step  = rot_count
        self.angle_slots = 360 // self.angle_step
        # pre-compute all the rotated images, and bitmap collision masks
        for i in range( 1, self.angle_slots ):
            rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate( bitmap, self.ANGLE_STEP * i )
            self.rotations.append( rotated_image )
        self._setRotationImage( 0 ) # sets initial image & rect

    def rotateRight( self ):
        if ( self.rotation == 0 ):
            self._setRotationImage( self.angle_slots - 1 )
        else:
            self._setRotationImage( self.rotation - 1 )

    def rotateLeft( self ):
        if ( self.rotation == self.angle_slots - 1 ):
            self._setRotationImage( 0 )
        else:
            self._setRotationImage( self.rotation + 1 )

    def _setRotationImage( self, rot_index ):
        """ Set the sprite image to the correct rotation """
        rot_index %= self.angle_slots
        self.rotation = rot_index
        # Select the pre-rotated image 
        self.image = self.rotations[ rot_index ]
        # We need to preserve the centre-position of the bitmap, 
        # as rotated bitmaps will (probably) not be the same size as the original
        centerx = self.rect.centerx
        centery = self.rect.centery
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( centerx, centery )

    def update( self ):
        self.rotateRight()  # do something
```

You could of-course pre-make the 12 frames of rotated bitmap in a graphics package, and just load them in at run-time.  I like the above method because if you decide to move to say 24 frames, it all happens with the change of a parameter.

The direction the image is "facing" is simply the current index of rotation ( the `self.rotation` ) in the class above.  For example, Imagine a "rotation" with just 4 frames - up/right/down/left.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Will implement it.